# Input file randomly does not show choose file box

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm dynamically creating an `input` like

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="user_file" class="upload-image">
```

and then open the box programmatically with

```
this.$el.trigger("click");
```

Where `this.$el` refers to the element ( I am using a `Backbone.View` ).

It worked perfectly till some day ago, now, randomly it does not open itself anymore, sometime it does not work since the first time, sometime after some instanciated views.

It has to be specified that the `view` get correctly instanciated and the `trigger function` correctly called, simply the box does not show.

It happens both in Chrome and Firefox.

I cannot think anything, I thought was a memory related problem, but from `window.performance.memory` it seems okay.

Any idea?

Comment: If it randomly works then the issue should be event-related. Share the relevant code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem is that I am not able to reproduce with couple class